# Implementing non-positional keyword arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-theory

I am trying to implement keyword arguments in Haskell, similar to the ones found in Ocaml. My goal is to have arguments that can be passed in any order, and can be partially applied in a function call (yielding a new function that takes the remaining keyword arguments).

I've tried to implement this using DataKinds and a type-class that represents "a value that can be converted into a function `a -> b`." The idea is that a function taking two keyword arguments, `foo` and `bar`, can be converted either to a function that looks like `foo -> bar -> x` or to a function that looks like `bar -> foo -> x`. This should be unambiguous so long as `foo` and `bar` have different types (and `x` isn't itself a function that takes `foo` or `bar`), which is what I've tried to achieve with the `Kwarg` GADT.

The functional dependency in the `Fun` class was meant to make the relationship between `f`, `a`, and `b` more explicit, but I'm not sure whether this actually helped. I get a compiler error with and without it.

I have enabled the following language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

Contents of `Quoter.hs`:

```
module Quoter where

import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)

data Kwarg :: Symbol -> * -> * where
  Value :: a -> Kwarg b a

class Fun f a b | f a -> b where
  runFun :: f -> a -> b

instance (Fun f' a' b) => Fun (a -> f') a' (a -> b) where
  runFun f a' = \a -> runFun (f a) a'

instance Fun (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) b where
  runFun = id
```

Contents of `Main.hs`:

```
module Main where

import Quoter

test :: (Num a) => Kwarg "test" a -> Kwarg "some" a -> a
test (Value i) (Value j) = i + j

main = putStrLn $ show $
  runFun test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int)
```

This is the error that I get when building with ghc:

```
Main.hs:18:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Kwarg "some" Int -> b’ with ‘Int’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘Fun (Kwarg "some" Int -> Int) (Kwarg "some" Int) Int’
            arising from a use of ‘runFun’
          instance ‘Fun (a -> f') a' (a -> b1)’ at <no location info>
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘runFun
           test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘show
         $ runFun
             test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int)’
      In the expression:
        putStrLn
        $ show
          $ runFun
              test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int)
```

Do you know what I need to change in order to get this to compile? Is this general approach sensible, and what do I need to understand better in order to get this to work?

Thanks!

Output of `ghc --version`:

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2
```

Comment: Do you know about the standard [record trick](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/haskell-anti-pattern-incremental-ad-hoc-parameter-abstraction/)? It will probably be a much better engineering tradeoff: much less implementation work, and a lot less cumbersome to use. Partial application can be achieved by leaving some fields uninitialized. The only thing you would be giving up is compiler support for noticing which fields still need values.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes, I'm aware of that trick. I'd like to see how well this implementation can work as a proof of concept. (You might have guessed from the filename `Quoter.hs` that this originally contained a TH QuasiQuoter to make it less cumbersome to use. I've removed that to make the example more self-contained/suitable for StackOverflow, but I'll add it back in once the types work.) EDIT: Compiler support for noticing which fields still need values is something I'd love to have, hence this implementation. :)

Comment: http://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/

Comment: @leftaroundabout does this support partial application? I couldn't see any discussion of that in the blog post. What I'm trying to implement gives you partial application with soundness checking (no run-time exceptions).

Comment: Besides the practical aspects, I'm also very interested in understanding the theory behind why what I'm trying to do doesn't work, and learning the theory that will make it work.

Comment: @JeromeBaum indeed it doesn't. It's an interesting question you're asking, but I think it's really tricky type-wise. I'll attempt an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your instances are overlapping:

```
instance (Fun f' a' b) => Fun (a -> f') a' (a -> b) where

instance Fun (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) b
  -- this is actually a special case of the above, with a ~ a' ~ KWarg name t
```

It becomes clearer if we replace the functional dependency (which is IMO usually a bit hard to reason about) with an equivalent associated type family:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Fun f a where
  type FRes f a :: *
  runFun :: f -> a -> FRes f a

instance Fun f' a' => Fun (a -> f') a' where
  type FRes (a -> f') a' = a -> FRes f' a'
  runFun f a' = \a -> runFun (f a) a'

instance Fun (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) where
  type FRes (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) = b
  runFun = id
```

In this case, the compiler message is pretty clear:

```
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      FRes (a -> f') a' = a -> FRes f' a'
        -- Defined at /tmp/wtmpf-file10498.hs:20:8
      FRes (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) = b
        -- Defined at /tmp/wtmpf-file10498.hs:24:8
   |
20 |   type FRes (a -> f') a' = a -> FRes f' a'
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Overlapping instances are a big problem, in particular when nontrivial type-level functions need to be resolved. However, it's not a problem that hasn't been encountered often before. A solution is to switch from the instance-clause-based type-level functions (i.e. FunDeps or associated type-families) to [closed type families](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#closed-type-families):

```
type family FRes f a where
  FRes (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) = b
  FRes (a -> f') a' = a -> FRes f' a'
```

To actually implement `runFun`, you still need a class with overlapping instances, however these can now be hacked to worked with GHC pragmas:

```
class Fun f a where
  runFun :: f -> a -> FRes f a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Fun f' a', FRes (a -> f') a' ~ (a->FRes f' a'))
               => Fun (a -> f') a' where
  runFun f a' = \a -> runFun (f a) a'

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Fun (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t) where
  runFun = id
```

As such, your test will now work.

Unfortunately it will *not* do what it's actually supposed to though: allow the argument order to be changed.

```
main = putStrLn $ show
  ( runFun test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int)
  , runFun test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "test" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "some" Int) )
```

gives

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file10498.hs:34:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Kwarg "some" Int -> b0’
                  with actual type ‘FRes
                                      (Kwarg "test" a0 -> Kwarg "some" a0 -> a0) (Kwarg "test" Int)’
      The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
    • The function ‘runFun’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘(Kwarg "test" a0 -> Kwarg "some" a0 -> a0)
                    -> Kwarg "test" Int
                    -> FRes
                         (Kwarg "test" a0 -> Kwarg "some" a0 -> a0) (Kwarg "test" Int)’
      has only two
      In the expression:
        runFun
          test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "test" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "some" Int)
      In the first argument of ‘show’, namely
        ‘(runFun
            test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "some" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "test" Int), 
          runFun
            test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "test" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "some" Int))’
   |
34 |   , runFun test (Value 5 :: Kwarg "test" Int) (Value 6 :: Kwarg "some" Int) )
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The essential problem is that type inference goes in the less favourable direction: from starting-values to end-results. This is the only avaible direction in most languages, but in Haskell it's almost always better to infer from the end result to the individual expressions, because only the outer result is always available for unification with the environment. In the end, that leads you to something like

```
type family FFun a b where
```

i.e. the type of function is determined from the result you want and the argument you can already supply. You would then not have overlapping instances based on whether the argument at hand happens to be the first one the function expects; rather you'd build up some sort of type-level map including all the keyed arguments and have the function accept one such map (or, equivalently, all the arguments in alphabetic order).

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. I'm still trying to understand it all. I agree that the instances are overlapping (and in fact, I think there are several instantiations of the first instance for my function `test`). I don't think either instance is a special case of the other one though (i.e. there are instances of each that have type parameters that won't unify with the corresponding parameters of the other). Is this understanding correct? (Although I agree that even the `test` example matches both instances.)

I'll try to understand type families and see if that gets me closer to a solution.

Comment: One often-misunderstood fact about class instances is _the constraint list isn't considered at all for resolution_. I.e. when the compiler typechecks an occurence of `runFun`, it just sees `instance Fun (a -> f') a'` and `instance Fun (Kwarg name t -> b) (Kwarg name t)`. Only _after_ deciding to pick the former will it then go on trying to resolve the extra `Fun f' a'` constraint. Thus you're right – in reality, the instances are different, but as far as instance _resolution_ is concerned, `Fun f' a' => Fun (a -> f') a'` is strictly more general.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the comment about the original instances. Those have three parameters. Does the compiler not try to unify all the parameters (ignoring any constraints)? (Perhaps due to the FunDep?)

Comment: I guess I answered my own question in that last comment - the FunDep means that the compiler won't consider the third argument `b` when deciding what instance to pick, right?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about that, but yeah – it wouldn't really be a functional relation `f,a -> b` if a-priori information about `b` could be used to decide what instance to pick.

Comment: @JeromeBaum Correct, I think. You've told it that there can only be one instance with a fixed `b` for any given `f` and `a`. If it ever needed the third argument to choose between two instances where the other two arguments could unify, the fundep would be a lie.